# Internet Explorer and Edge Treating Block as Inline-Block

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

On my homepage and a few others, Internet Explorer and Edge are placing my *read more* links next to tables that use `display: block` value. The table and the links are in separate `div`s.  It seems that the Microsoft browsers are confusing `block` with `inline-block`.

Anyone had this problem?  Are there alternatives that function in IE and Edge?

http://tenbooksamonth.com/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see such behavior is some-how caused by the `word-wrap` property in you responsive.css file. If you turn it off, site looks fine.

Before
[image: Before image]

After
[image: After image]

p.s. Not sure what are actual display modes for the divs, as they are positioned thru some grid framework.

Comment: It seemed like your solution would work.  I checked out your suggestions via developer tools in Edge, and unchecking the break-word worked there, but when applied on the css file, it didn't change things.  The only thing that's had an effect so far, was removing the display: block, which creates all kinds of other issues.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot how results looks like after you applied changed in css file? Can you check in devtools that the 'word-wrap' property is not present? (e.g. css files are new, not cached ones).

Comment: I updated my post. After you made changes to the css file is it now still like "before" or like "after" or something else?

Comment: I just re-checked again, and you're right word-wrap is still showing in dev tools. Not sure why. I cleared caches in the browser and on my site.  Just double checked the responsive.css file and the word-wrap is commented out.  And by the way... thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Okay.  Just did some fishing around and what do you know? I have two files named responsive.css.  I'm using Drupal with a customized Zen theme, so I'm not familiar with many of the files and folders.  I deleted the word-wrap.  The problem is gone.   Thank you so very much!!

Comment: Great to hear! :) I think you should mark your question as answered in that case.

Comment: I did try.  Unfortunately, I'm too new to the forum to "up" an answer. But thank you all the same.